# How to select column values which throw an error if cast to a new type

Tags: sql, t-sql, casting, type-conversion

I need an sql query to give me the following:

All the values in a column of type **varchar(50)** which will NOT convert or will throw an error if cast / converted to an **int**.

E.g.

row 1: '1'

row 2: '2'

row 3: '3a'

row 4: '4.5'

I need row 3....however there are tens of thousands of rows.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can use regular expressions to select the values that contain characters other than the number 0-9 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933213(SQL.80).aspx

e.g.,

```
SELECT * WHERE ISNUMERIC(column)=1
```

Edit:  Actually, this wouldn't quite cut it if you want precisely int only.  Try this instead.  If you only want int range, then throw in a range check as well (feeling a bit lazy at this point).

```
SELECT * 
WHERE 
       ISNUMERIC(column)=1 
       OR (CEILING(CONVERT(float, column))!=FLOOR(CONVERT(float, column)))
```

Comment: unfortunately that lets float values through, im sorry if my example mislead, but i need to test if convertible to an integer.

Comment: Yep.  Give the second one a whirl.

Comment: Cool thanks, if you change it to ISNUMERIC(column) <> 1 then it catches float values too. Cheers!